# Enable application pool 32-bit mode on 64-bit server

Tags: asp.net, application-pool

We have `64-bit Windows server` and we need to explicitly enable the `32-bit mode` in the Application Pool used by our web site, because the `MS Jet Engine Data Provider used to import data from Excel` does not run.

I am not sure, if we enable the `32-bit` mode will we still get the advantage of `64-bit` Server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In IIS 7.x, there is a Advanced Settings property of the application pool called "Enable 32-bit Applications". If you run the application as a 32-bit applications it should be able to use 4 GB but obviously no more. So, in that respect, it can take advantage of running on a 64-bit server. On a 32-bit server (without special switches) it would only be able to use the 2GB of address space allocated to applications (the other 2 GB is presumed to be used by the OS).

Comment: a good article on this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2007/11/03/iis7-running-32-bit-and-64-bit-asp-net-versions-at-the-same-time-on-different-worker-processes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

ACE driver 64 bit is now available as a replacement of Jet driver. So you can use it instead,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/01/21/how-to-get-a-x64-version-of-jet.aspx

(Read the last few paragraphs.)