# How to solve this error creating an ActiveX object?

Tags: .net, activex

From an ASP.net application I have to create an Access object using CreateObject method. If I run it in the development server in Visual Studio the application works fine but when I publish it as a virtual directory in IIS the following error appears:

*ActiveX component cannot be created. Microsoft.VisualBasic System.Object CreateObject(System.String, System.String)*

I´ve been looking for the solution for days but none of them has worked: I've set impersonate to true, I've set Access permissions in DCOM, permissions to the user ASPNET but I can't make it work. IIS is on a virtual machine using VMWare.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is access installed on the server?

Comment: Can you give more details about the error.. any error code / stack trace etc? pls add in question .. also add the code

Comment: Also which version of MS Access and IIS are you using?

Comment: CreateObject() produces unhelpful exceptions.  The usual problem is trying to load a 32-bit version of the COM object when your web app runs in 64-bit mode.  Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216192/enable-application-pool-32-bit-mode-on-64-bit-server).  SysInternals' ProcMon utility can tell you more.

Comment: That's not the problem. My processor in server is 32 bits and so is IIS 6.